# How to COUNT a field not directly related to the where expression on ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to find out How many students are enrolled in all units, that are associated with a particular course.

I have tried.

```
SELECT        COUNT(studentID) AS Expr1
FROM            Course CROSS JOIN
                         Enrolment
WHERE        (Course.courseCode = 'S4000')
```

But i am getting 3 , each time for the different course codes.

It should be 1 for S4000. I have 3 students in total.

Comment: Post your table def please...

Comment: Cross join is not what you want.

Comment: As you're new here, I remember that you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you think it solved (or helped to solve) your problem

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us columns names, so I create:

```
SELECT cu.courseCode, COUNT(e.StudentID) AS tot_Students
FROM COURSEUNIT cu INNER JOIN ENROLMENT e
ON cu.unitCode = e.couseCode    
GROUP BY cu.courseCode
```

Comment: @David: take a look now... it should work, but where are columns names?

Comment: Thanks, but i kind of dont understand it still. .  I have updated the first post with the column names. Could you update the code please?

Comment: @David: it works, I've just tested it. Which error do you have?

Comment: @David: you have to help yourself, because error is easy to understand. You wrote _courseCode_ in COURSEUNIT table, while you have _couseCode_ on ENROLMENT table. Are you sure of those names? Come on, it's easy to correct them in my query if you made something wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of what happens in cross join each record in 1st table is get related other record 2nd  table .in your case suppose there are 3 student and 3 courses

Student  table

Id | Name

1  | abc

2  | pqr

3  | xyz

Courses

Code | Name

S4000 | c1

S4001 | c2

S4002 | c3

Cross join table

Student.Id | Student.Name | Courses.code |courses.name

1| abc|   S4000 | c1

2  | pqr|   S4000 | c1

3  | xyz|   S4000 | c1

1| abc|   S4001 | c2

2  | pqr|   S4001 | c2

3  | xyz|   S4001 | c2

1| abc|   S4002 | c3

2  | pqr|   S4002 | c3

3  | xyz|   S4002 | c3

Now you can see their are 3 records created for each courses so you are getting 3 answer each time.

so in your query you should have same common field to get required records such as there will Fourier key relationship

you add common field in where clause  like

SELECT        COUNT(studentID) AS Expr1

FROM            Course CROSS JOIN
                        Enrolment
WHERE        (Course.courseCode = 'S4000')

```
        and Course.studentID=Enrolment.studentID
```

OR you can use inner join on common field